# Since update to CE 1.9.2.2 Cron throwing error

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.5

After updating, via Connect, to CE 1.9.2.2 from CE 1.9.1.0 I am getting errors from the cron email. The error is:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so' -
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so' -
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39

The command in my cPanel crontab is:

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /bin/sh ~/www/cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The error is being emailed to me.  The system has mcrypt, but cPanel compiles it into apache, not as a loadable module.  Any ideas as to what would be causing this?  The MAGE exception log shows nothing new since the update, and the MAGE system log is similarly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was interested in the outcome. The solution to this problem was a yum update of the entire system.  Apparently I was missing, or using outdated, libraries that the cron job needed.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are not loading this lib twice :

```
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so
```

this is what error about. open phpinfo page and look for these lines:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:
Scan this dir for additional .ini files:
Additional .ini files parsed:
```

check for any php.ini overrides or second mcrypt.ini file.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so does not exist because cPanel compiles it directly into PHP/Apache. This fact is clearly stated on their support forum.   The items you mentioned show a single php.ini file in /usr/local/lib that has a single reference to a dll for mcrpyt. This reference is commented out.  Also, I saw the errors in other sites where mcrypt was loading twice. These were a different error than this one.  My error clearly states the file simply can not be found...which is expected since it is compiled in and not a loadable module.